# Microsoft Access 2007: enabling setValue, trusted locations etc

Tags: ms-access-2007

I want to use **setValue** in Macro. I read that if my database is not trusted then setValue will not appear in list of available Actions.

Originally when I started my database a little message was displayed saying that my DB was not trusted and indeed setValue was not available.

So I follow the recipe of adding my database's location C:\Users\Me\MyTrustedDatabases to the Trust Center's list of trusted locations, I've verified that "disable all trusted locations" is not set.

Now when I start my DB the message about the DB not being trusted is **not** displayed. And yet I don't see the setValue Action in the drop-down list of actions.

Suggestions for what I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer: Select the Show All Actions option in the Design ribbon.